# C# - Comparação de data com LINQ não traz o resultado esperado

Tags: c#, linq, filtro, linq-to-sql

Temos um banco de dados Oracle com uma View.

Temos que pegar o total de cana colhida somando a coluna QT_LIQUIDO de acordo com o dia.

Fizemos o código em C#, mas está com um comportamento inesperado.

Se fazemos a comparação da data direto no dbContext dá certo e ele faz a soma do valor.

Mas se já chamarmos o dbContext o resultado da soma é sempre 0.

Observem o código usado abaixo:

```
//Data que vem no body do POST (30/04/2018)
DateTime data_filtro = Convert.ToDateTime(filtros.data);

//Filtrando a safra direto no banco
var cana = _db.DbCanaTotal.Where(u => u.CD_SAFRA.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(filtros.safra))); 

//A partir do filtro de safra um IEnumerable (DÁ ZERO A SOMA)
dto.dia = cana.Where(r => r.DT_MOVIMENTO.Equals(data_filtro)).Sum(r => r.QT_LIQUIDO);

//Direto do banco (DÁ CERTO A SOMA COM o WHERE IGUAL AO DE CIMA)
dto.dia = _db.DbCanaTotal.Where(u => u.DT_MOVIMENTO.Equals(data_filtro)).Sum(x => x.QT_LIQUIDO);
```

Eu e meu amigo não sabemos mais o que fazer

Comment: você teste assim: `_db.DbCanaTotal.Where(u => u.DT_MOVIMENTO == data_filtro)` e me fala o resultado! não use `Equals` tem comportamento diferentes... !!! eu semprei usei `==`

Comment: e confira os seus registros e filtros, `2019-04-17 22:06:35:345` é diferente de `2019-04-17 00:00:000`

Comment: @WitnessTruth Conseguiu avançar?